# Visual Studio 2019: Class diagram tabs won't stay pinned; Class diagram tabs duplicate themselves when re-pinned

Tags: visual-studio, class-diagram

I have a C# solution that builds. It has multiple class diagram `*.cd` files

I open the solution using: `File -> Recent Projects and Solutions`

I pin all my `*.cd` files:

[image]

I close and re-open the solution using `File -> Recent Projects and Solutions`. All the `*.cd` file tabs become unpinned:

[image]

I re-pin a `*.cd` file:

[image]

The `*.cd` file I re-pinned now has two tabs: one pinned and one un-pinned.

[image]

I typically then close the second, un-pinned `*.cd` file.

*Side note: If a pinned .cd file tab happens to be selected at the time I close the solution, then when I re-open the solution, that particular .cd file tab is still pinned.*

Is this behavior as-designed, or is there a way to have `*.cd` files stay pinned across solution editing sessions?

FYI:

[image]